# Oracle Listener Throws error ORA12505

Tags: oracle11g

While connecting Oracle Database i am getting error as "Listener refused the following connection with error as ORA12505: TNS Listener does not currently know of SID given in current descriptor ". Please help me on how to solve this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restarted my PC solves this problem. But don't know the root cause for this.